# Junos creates console object instead of device object

Tags: junos-automation

I'm working on a zero-day configuration tool and I'm trying to deploy a configuration to a EX2200 switch. I'm using the PyEZ framework to connect to the device:

```
dev = Device(mode='serial', port='/dev/ttyUSB0',user="user",
               password="password", gather_facts=True)
dev.open()
```

The object dev should be an instance of the class Device, but when I check its class with dev._ *class* _ it says class 'jnpr.junos.console.Console'. 
I want to pass dev a configuration through a jinja2 template,

```
cu = Config(dev)    
rsp=cu.load(template_path=template_path, 
template_vars=config_data,merge=True)
```

but it gives me the following error when loading the configuration:

```
Error loading config: 'Console' object has no attribute '_j2ldr'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a PyEZ bug which has been addressed by [#753](https://github.com/Juniper/py-junos-eznc/pull/753)